# Can pyinstaller make a desktop file (with an icon) for an Ubuntu python app

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller, desktop

I'm building a python app which is to pack up as a single executable and work on Windows, MacOS and Linux. Have made a lot of progress and am using a workflow on Github to build using pyinstaller for each OS. Most things are working fine.

Right now I am working on getting an icon onto the executable instead of the default system icon.

I have a `spec` file for pyinstaller and I have a section where the icon is mentioned:

```
exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='my_app_name',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon='images/my_icon.ico'
)
```

This seems to work well for Windows and the output exe file has my icon which is great.
My question is, is there a way to do this for Linux. I know that normally for Linux you need to build a `.desktop` file, so I guess the question is three-fold:

1. Is there a way to give a file an icon without a desktop file (in Linux)?

or

2. Is there a way to somehow build and connect a desktop file to my Linux file in pyinstaller?

or

3. Is there some python way to self-create a desktop file for my python app?

Thanks

Comment: You should check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397076/how-to-create-executable-desktop-entry-icon

Comment: Thank you @Alexander - I can make desktop entries for myself. However, when I install other applications to Linux - they come with an icon, so somehow there is some magic happening during installation which means I have an icon - like in Chromium, Sublime or LibreOffice. So is there a way I can do that in pyinstaller (or within my linux executable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found a a way to do it - not really in pyinstaller, but it works for me.

I am building my app(s) using Github's Workflow feature - so we have a file called `python_build.yml` under `/.github/workflows`

So, after building the executable with pyinstaller into a single file I have:

```
- name: Assign artifacts
  if: github.event_name == 'release'
  uses: knicknic/os-specific-run@v1.0.4
  with:
    macos: echo "artifact_path=My_app.dmg" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    windows: echo "artifact_path=dist/my_app.exe" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV
    linux: echo "artifact_path=dist/my_app.deb" >> $GITHUB_ENV
- name: Create DMG app (for MacOS)
  if: github.event_name == 'release' && runner.os == 'macOS'
  run: |
    rm -rf dist/my_app
    brew install create-dmg
    create-dmg --app-drop-link 100 100 "${{env.artifact_path}}" dist/
- name: Create DEB file for Ubuntu
  if: github.event_name == 'release' && runner.os == 'linux'
  run: |
    cp dist/my_app my-app/usr/share/bin/my_app 
    rm -rf my-app/usr/share/bin/hold
    fakeroot dpkg-deb --build my-app
- name: Sleep while DEB build happens
  if: github.event_name == 'release' && runner.os == 'linux'
  run: sleep 30s
  shell: bash
- name: Copy over DEB to dist folder
  if: github.event_name == 'release' && runner.os == 'linux'
  run: |
    cp my-app.deb dist/my-appi.deb
    rm -rf dist/my_app
- name: Add artifacts to release
  if: github.event_name == 'release'
  uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1.11.2
  with:
    allowUpdates: true
    replacesArtifacts: false
    artifacts: ${{env.artifact_path}}
```

So, there's a couple of important points to add to this. I have saved in my Git repository a small directory structure named my-app. I don't think this is the [web page I used](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Debian_package_structure) but it's similar. Basically a folder named my-app with two folders underneath it : `DEBIAN` and `usr`. In the `DEBIAN` there is one file called `control` with something like this in it:

```
Package: my-app
Version: 1.1-7
Section: Utility
Priority: optional
Architecture: i386
Depends: 
Homepage: https://www.ourwebsite.com/
Maintainer: Kibi Hofmann <kibi@ourwebsite.com>
Installed-Size: 31300
Description: Useful app for your use
 No dependencies or significant conflicts.
 This app is used to do your stuff
```

Under `usr` is a folder `share` which has three more folders under it `applications`, `bin` and `icons`.
The `bin` folder has (in my Git repository) an empty file called `hold` just so that the directory structure is maintained in Git - you can see that the `hold` file is deleted and replaced by the compiled binary after pyinstaller is finished. The Desktop file itself is under `applications` and looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=My App
GenericName=My cool app
Comment=Keep your computer happy
Exec=/usr/share/bin/my-app
Icon=myr_icon
Terminal=false
Categories=Application
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

There's such a pip library as a **auto-py-to-exe**. It's UI for pyinstaller and it makes it quite easier to create exe. Try to apply icon though that stuff.
I think it also should work for Linux as for Windows. But for me there were some errors if l created few files with same name and different icons. Not sure if it was problem of pyinstaller.

1. It gives you a possibility to select icon (.ico file). I can guess that your error with icon due to wrong path to file or place from where you run cmd
2. You can try to write another script that use **pyinstaller** to do it. But if clearly understood - you can create exe only using this library. If you need shortcut - it can be created by using **os.system** by another python script.
   [Auto-py-to-exe UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3fl9.png)

Comment: This is not accurate.  Neither PyInstaller nor Auto-py-exe can create a linux executable with an icon.

Comment: @Alexander Understood, my bad. Thought that would work

Comment: It does work for windows and mac, but linux doesn't work the same way.

Comment: Hi @Alexander - thanks for your comment. Do you know anything that *would* work?